# Simulate the distribution of the median

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution, simulation, median

[image: Question]

I have done part(a); now I need to do part(b): I want to simulate the distribution of the median $M$ using R. I don't know how to work it out.

And for part(c), do I need to use R as well?

This is what I have done

```
medians <- vector(length=100)
for (i in 1:100) {
     x <- rnorm(n=15,mean=0,sd=1)
     medians[i] <- median(x)
 }

hist(medians)
```

Comment: I use >M<-rnorm(15,0,1), but guess it's not sufficient.

Comment: `rnorm(15)` (you don't need the "0,1" since those are the defaults) gives you a sample of size 15. You need the median of that sample, right? So calculate the median and put *that* into `M`. You'll also save yourself a lot of effort if you learn to use `replicate`

Comment: I will have a try!

Comment: >replicate(15,mean(rnorm(15))), is that correct？

Comment: What does "mean" do? Do you think the mean function computes sample medians?

Comment: nah...replicate(15,median(rnorm(15)))?

Comment: What does the first argument to replicate do? Your level of effort seems to be far below what's expected on these problems. You can expect hints for reasonable level of work. If we have to hold your hand through every step, your question will simply be closed.

Comment: sorry i'm beginner.

Comment: No need to apologize for being a beginner; just do your best to actually begin! FWIW, I see some initial effort here, but you've gotta keep it coming. Use `?replicate` to learn how it works. Also, if your question does get put on hold, keep editing it and nominate it for reopening once you've done all you can. It's not irreversible.

Comment: ...and we're not trying to get rid of you! It's just site policy to require that you meet us halfway (and you'll probably learn more that way).

Comment: Thanks for coming back with some more (I formatted your code). The code is fine, it works (but as I suggested earlier, replicate is better). If you haven't been given a sample size to use, I'd suggest a much larger sample size (when I did it the yesterday I used 10000, but your approach may be a bit slow for so many). You also need to compare it with something - the approximating density. It's possible to plot both the histogram (but you'll need `freq=FALSE` for this) and the approximate normal density on the same display. Alternatively, you could try a qqplot to compare. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... If you have enough simulations (and in the case of a histogram with density drawn on top - a small enough bin width the R defaults are much too wide) you can see how close the approximation is and where/how it differs.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code:

```
x <- replicate(10000,median(rnorm(15))) ## simulate 10000 sample median of norm size 15

plot(density(sqrt(15)*x))  

z <- seq(-5,5,length.out = 200)

lines(z,dnorm(z,sd=sqrt(pi/2)),type = "l",col = "red") ## comparing with the asymptotic density
```